# Search the list and take item based on the index value of the match

Tags: c#, linq

```
var slots = new List<slot>()
{
    new slot { Ids = "2,3,4,6,8,9,1" },
    new slot { Ids = "10,11,12,13,1,7" },
    new slot { Ids = "1,4,6,5,10,11,29,40,7" },
};
```

Above all the list have "1" but If I search with one then it should return the 3d list because of the index, so just need to compare the index also and need to take that one.

IF I search with "7" then it should return the 2nd list.

In overall if more than one matching result then it should return the one list based on the position

IF match is there take the array IF find another match take the array in which the match has the lowest index.

How to achieve this?

Comment: `Split()` along with `Array.IndexOf()`. Anything you've tried so far ?

Comment: Are you able to change `slot`? Because it looks like `Ids` has the wrong datatype and instead of a comma-delimited string it should be an `int[]`.

Comment: I _kinda_ get, why searching for "1" should return the third slot (because it has a "1" in "first" position, right?). But I'm completely stumped why "7" should return the second slot. There, the "7" is in the sixth position, not seventh... -- also, when talking about the "index", it is usually assumed that it is zero based, so that's confusing, too...

Comment: Hi @Corak,
If more than one matching list then it should return the lowest position list

Comment: sorry mate but like Corak I am also puzzled about what the actual criterion here is. Please try to elaborate a little more

Comment: But as far as I understand it, **none** of the slots would match "7", as none of them has a "7" in seventh position. -- and if the criteria is just "has a '7' in it", why wouldn't "1" then return the first slot?

Comment: have you tried to solve it without linq already? You are asking specifically for a linq solution here? I have the feeling that linq would yield not the most readable solution in your case

Comment: @Corak it's not the position. IF match is there take the array, IF find another match take the array in which the match has the lowest index. The `7` in the second list is on the 6-th position which is lower than in the third list

Comment: Hi @Corak,
"7" is not a position, it is a keyword to search from the list

Comment: @MongZhu - aahh, I think I got it now.

Comment: So basically something like `slots.Where(slot => slot.Ids.Contains(number)).OrderBy(slot => slot.Ids.IndexOf(number)).FirstOrDefault()`?

Comment: @Corak almost, I think you need a `slot.Ids.Split(';').Contains(number)` otherwise you would match also 11, 12, 13 when looking for a 1. You would need also to split again when ordering for index

Comment: @MongZhu - right. Which strengthens the point that `Slot.Ids` should probably be an `IList<int>` of some kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to split by the comma and then order by the index. Since split will return an array you would need to create a list first:

```
slot candidate = (from s in slots
    let parts = s.Ids.Split(',')
    where parts.Contains(searchItem)
    orderby Array.IndexOf(parts, searchItem)
    select s).FirstOrDefault();
```

detail: the `let` part allows you to save the split result temporarily in the variable parts. This way you can avoid spliting again when the order by clause is executed.

Comment: You might "avoid spliting again when the order by clause is executed" but you certainly iterate the list twice with with the `.ToList()` and the `.IndexOf(searchItem)`. So instead of splitting twice and creating two arrays you split once and call `.ToList()` once thus creating two arrays.

Comment: So, in fact you're creating an array twice and iterating over the arrays three times.

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks for the hint. I changed it to use `Array.IndexOf` to avoid the `ToList` call.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach that avoids all of the muck `IndexOf` or `Contains`:

```
List<slot> slots = new List<slot>()
{
    new slot { Ids = "2,3,4,6,8,9,1" },
    new slot { Ids = "10,11,12,13,1,7" },
    new slot { Ids = "1,4,6,5,10,11,29,40,7" },
};

IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, slot>> query =
    from slot in slots
    let Ids = slot.Ids.Split(',')
    from x in Ids.Select((number, index) => (number, index))
    orderby x.index
    group slot by x.number;

Dictionary<string, slot> map = query.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.First());
```

With this you get the following:

- `map["1"]` gives `slot { Ids = "1,4,6,5,10,11,29,40,7" }`
- `map["7"]` gives `slot { Ids = "10,11,12,13,1,7" }`

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
var result = slots.Select(x=>x.Ids.Split(new[]{','}))
                      .Where(x=>x.Contains(itemToSearch))
                      .OrderBy(x=>Math.Abs((Array.IndexOf(x,itemToSearch) + 1) - Convert.ToInt32(itemToSearch)))
                      .Select(x=>string.Join(",",x))
                      .First();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 private slot search(List<slot> slots, string searchItem)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < slots.Count; i++)
                {
                    var slotIds = slots[i].Ids.Split(',');
                    if (slotIds.contains(searchItem))
                        return slots[i];
                }

                return null;
            }
```

Comment: No, this one will return the first match always

Comment: @BVWinoya, If you want all, then add it in local list and return all matched list

Comment: Is it looks better?

Comment: you are actually missing the comparison of the lowest index

Comment: Thanks @MongZhu, I got it

Comment: This code has numerous syntax errors **and** it only ever returns the first slot that contains the `searchItem`. It doesn't answer the question in a useful way.